# Serialization XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, keyvaluepair

i need the following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" dateprodstart="20180319" heureprodstart="12:08:36" 
dateprodend="20180319" heureprodend="12:12:45" version="1.21" encoding="utf- 8"?>

<ListItems>

<item>
    <filename>test5</filename>
    <destination>O</destination>
    <test1>EVA00</test1>
    <test2>ko</test2>
</item>

<item>
    <filename>test</filename>
    <destination>O</destination>
    <test1>xxxx</test1>
    <test2>xxxx</test2>
</item>

...

</ListItems>
```

I have the object item with the field (sorted): filename, destination, test1, test2. And i need the list of item.

What's the best way? Datacontract or XmlSerialization? Because i need customize the name of List and the name of nodelement. Originally the object item was a dictionary key, value:

filename, test5;
destination,0;
test1, EVA00
test2, ko.

Could you help me?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string version = "1.21";
            string dateprodstart =   DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string heureprodstart=  DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
            string dateprodend =   DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string heureprodend =  DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");


            Dictionary<string,List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>() {
                { "Item", new List<string>() {
                            "filename, test5; destination,0; test1, EVA00; test2, ko",
                            "filename, test5; destination,0; test1, EVA00; test2, ko",
                            "filename, test5; destination,0; test1, EVA00; test2, ko",
                            "filename, test5; destination,0; test1, EVA00; test2, ko"
                          }
                }
            };
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf- 8\"?><ListItems></ListItems>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement listItems = doc.Root;

            listItems.Add(new XAttribute[] {
                new XAttribute("dateprodstart",dateprodstart),
                new XAttribute("heureprodstart",heureprodstart ),
                new XAttribute("dateprodend",dateprodend),
                new XAttribute("heureprodend",heureprodend),
                new XAttribute("version",version)
            });

            foreach (string item in dict["Item"].AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement xItem = new XElement("item");
                listItems.Add(xItem);

                string[] elements = item.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                foreach (string element in elements)
                {

                    string[] csv = element.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    XElement newElement = new XElement(csv[0].Trim(), csv[1].Trim());
                    xItem.Add(newElement);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataContract is best here in this case. Also you can see the general [differences](http://www.cnblogs.com/asingna/archive/2011/11/06/2237904.html).

Comment: [DataContract()]
    [KnownType(typeof(InspireComponent))]
    [KnownType(typeof(ListInspireComponent))]
    public class InspireComponent
    {
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public int position;
        [DataMember(Name = "Key")]
        public string key;
        [DataMember(Name ="Value")]
        public string defaultvalue;